# How to calculate energy consumption between two instants?

Tags: java, android

I have an android app and a server side java code. I want to be able to calculate energy spent between two instants of time in both android and pure Java. How can I do that. I know about `dumpsys batterystats` but I am unable to find how can I parse the data obtained from it to find the relevant information from within my app.

Comment: There is no standard way to report on energy usage in Java(tm).   In fact, it is likely that a typical Windows / Linux / MacOS computer is not capable of measuring it at all.  (Tools like powerTOP - see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/304356/system-energy-consumption-monitoring - only *estimate* power consumption.)

Comment: Okay I'll try powerTop..I dont even need a very accurate detailing. Also for the other half, how to parse `dumpsys batterystats` from within the app. How do I write a code that can understand it when even I don't understand what it says.